# JSP imports directive containing semicolon( ;) not working in Tomcat 8 and above. but works in tomcat version below 8. how can one over come this?

Tags: jsp, tomcat8

Recently `upgraded tomcat from 7.5 to tomcat 8.0.27.` 
After upgrading got an error as:

> 'unable to compile JSP'

The above error is because of a semicolon in JSP import directive. 
I have more than 1000 JSP having semicolon. How can I bypass semicolon in tomcat 8.0.27? I removed semicolon and it works fine.

```
import="java.sql.*,ubq.util.UDate, myFile.order.OrderPlacement;" %>
```

I cannot manually alter the JSP import tag one by one. Any other solution to this, apart from the above is fine.

Comment: Write a program that removes the semicolon. Or just use a command line utility, or your IDE, to do it for you. Search/Replace with regexp is your friend.

Comment: thanks i am working on it. isn't there any configuration in Apache tomcat to avoid semicolon ?